# orange pi lite pcm5102 i2s

Tags: audio, dac, orange-pi, i2s

Good people, please tell me how to connect pcm5102 to orange pi. I'm trying to connect https://www.ozon.ru/product/i2s-interfeys-pcm5102-dac-decoder-gy-pcm5102-i2s-modul-dlya-raspberry-phat-867322416/ to my orange pi lite, but there is no sound I can get it, the device is there, the drivers are installed, I tried both armbian and volmio, it finds the device, but there is no sound.

Here's my pinout:

```
VIN - 2 VCC-5V
GND - 6 GND
LCK - 7 PWM1 (PA6)
DIN - 8 UART3_TX (PA13)
BCK - 11 UART2_RX (PA1)
SCK - 14 GND
```

Here is an example of how a device is detected

```
root@orangepilite:~# aplay -L
null
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
hw:CARD=I2Smaster,DEV=0
I2S-master, 1c22000.i2s-pcm5102a-hifi pcm5102a-hifi-0
Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=I2Smaster,DEV=0
I2S-master, 1c22000.i2s-pcm5102a-hifi pcm5102a-hifi-0
Hardware device with all software conversions
sysdefault:CARD=I2Smaster
I2S-master, 1c22000.i2s-pcm5102a-hifi pcm5102a-hifi-0
Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=I2Smaster,DEV=0
I2S-master, 1c22000.i2s-pcm5102a-hifi pcm5102a-hifi-0
Direct sample mixing device
```

Here I am testing the sound:

```
root@orangepilite:~# speaker-test -D hw:CARD=I2Smaster,DEV=0 -t wav -c 2

speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is hw:CARD=I2Smaster,DEV=0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
WAV file(s)
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 32 to 131072
Period size range from 16 to 65536
Using max buffer size 131072
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 32768
was set buffer_size = 131072
0 - Front Left
1 - Front Right
Time per period = 0.767988
0 - Front Left
1 - Front Right
Time per period = 2.743570
0 - Front Left
```

Could not get sound on either armbian 6.6.16 or volume,

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I've been picking for a week =(

Comment: Please have a careful read through the description of the orange-pi tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/orange-pi/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that we still needed to solder jumpers behind the board and everything worked.

Here's how it turned out for me: I installed volumio on the OS and everything worked right away.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks to Himbeer for suggesting and pointing to an article that helped solve the problem.

https://macsbug.wordpress.com/2021/02/19/web-radio-of-m5stack-pcm5102a-i2s-dac/